# Is it possible to load regex from external files in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I want to read regular expressions from a external file in Ruby. For example, I want to substitute a big string loading every regex from a file and running gsub for each. Each regex is separated by newlines on the file.

The external file would be like this:

```
engenharia d[ae] computação
ci[êe]ncias? d[ae] computação
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure! You can create a regex simply by using `Regex.new "my string"`. To put it together with reading a file:

```
regexen = []
File.open("myfile.txt", "r") do |f|
  while line = f.gets.chomp
    regexen << Regexp.new line
  end
end
```